# What is the story of Samaveda Shakas destroyed by Indra?

Tags: indra, sama-veda

While reading one [research thesis](https://sg.inflibnet.ac.in/bitstream/10603/138507/8/08_chapter%20i.pdf) from [Shodhaganga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shodhganga), I've noticed following line at the information about Shakas on Samaveda.

> According  to  Śaunaka  there  were  1000  śākhās,  **but  they  were  destroyed  by  Indra**  when  they  studied  by  the  pupils   on  the  day   of  Anadhyāya<sup>27</sup>.
>
> ---
>
> <sup>27 सामवेदस्य किल सहस्रभेदाः भवन्ति । एष्वनध्यायेष्वधीयानास्ते शतक्रतुवजेणाभिहताः ।
>
> Caranavyuha,3.1.</sup>

It says that Shakhas of Samavedas were destroyed by Indra, citing sanskrit text from Charanavyuha which is a work of [Shaunaka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaunaka) which [mention](https://archive.org/details/caranavyuha/page/n49) the quoted line.

So, What is the story of Indra destroyed the [Shakas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shakha) of Samaveda?

Comment: [Found some more info recently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qX9an.png)